# jLabel field is not updating when applet is embedded in jsp

Tags: java, swing, jsp, applet

`I have created swings GUI using applets i used string array for setting text to the jLabel, in applet window jLabel is working fine and showing the text according to the String array index but when I embed this applet in jsp page to run this in browser jLabel field is not updating at all please reply.

Comment: Show some code, please

Comment: <APPLET code="tutorials.me.niapp.class" archive="nishanth.jar" height="400" width="600">

Comment: just i used the above to run applet in browser it should run another java file and by that it updates the string array

Comment: by that string array only jLabel text is to be set i used jLabel.settext(str[0]);